# How to write a Reg Expression of a string that contains two tilde ~ , or two underscore

Tags: flutter, dart

Asterisk is working well. But I haven't figured out how to write an expression for underscore and tilde... I have tried multiple combinations. Please ignore what you see on the code below.

```
   else if (message.text.contains("_")) {
        message.text.trim().splitMapJoin(RegExp(r'/_(._?)_/'), onMatch: (m) {
          textParts.add(TextSpan(
              text: m.group(1), style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)));
          return '';
        }, onNonMatch: (String text) {
          textParts.add(TextSpan(text: text));
          return ' ';
        });
      } 

       else if (message.text.contains("*")) {
        message.text.trim().splitMapJoin(RegExp(r'\*(.*?)\*'), onMatch: (m) {
          textParts.add(TextSpan(
              text: m.group(1), style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)));
          return '';
        }, onNonMatch: (String text) {
          textParts.add(TextSpan(text: text));
          return ' ';
        });
      } 

      else if (message.text.contains("~")) {
        message.text.trim().splitMapJoin(RegExp(r'\~(.~?)\~'), onMatch: (m) {
          textParts.add(TextSpan(
              text: m.group(1), style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough)));
          return '';
        }, onNonMatch: (String text) {
          textParts.add(TextSpan(text: text));
          return ' ';
        });
      }
```

Comment: Underscores and tildes don't have any special meaning in regular expressions.  They don't need to be escaped.

Comment: it is `'_(.*?)_'`

Comment: @pskink Let me try that.

Comment: @jamesdlin, So how can I approach such scenario?

Comment: @AlexMaina You never explained what your code is *supposed* to do.  If you want to match a string that contains two or more underscores, then `RegExp(r'_.*_')` should work.  If you want the match to include exactly two underscores, then `RegExp(r'_[^_]*_`).  Tildes would just use `~` instead of `_`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a function that returns a `TextSpan` based on input `String`:

```
TextSpan rich(String input) {
  final styles = {
    '_': const TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
    '*': const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    '~': const TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough),
  };
  final spans = <TextSpan>[];
  input.trim().splitMapJoin(RegExp(r'([_*~])(.*?)\1'), onMatch: (m) {
    spans.add(TextSpan(text: m.group(2), style: styles[m.group(1)]));
    return '';
  }, onNonMatch: (String text) {
    spans.add(TextSpan(text: text));
    return '';
  });
  return TextSpan(style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24), children: spans);
}
```

you can test it by calling:

`final span = rich('some _italic_ word, some in *bold* and ~lineThrough~ works too');`

**EDIT**

if you need multi styles like `_*foo*_` for both italic and bold styles, you could do it by recursive calling `rich()` function:

```
TextSpan rich(String input, {TextStyle? style}) {
  const styles = {
    '_': TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
    '*': TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    '~': TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough),
  };
  final spans = <TextSpan>[];
  final pattern = RegExp(r'([_*~])(.*?)\1');
  input.trim().splitMapJoin(pattern, onMatch: (m) {
    final input = m.group(2)!;
    final style = styles[m.group(1)];
    spans.add(
      pattern.hasMatch(input)?
      rich(input, style: style) : TextSpan(text: input, style: style)
    );
    return '';
  }, onNonMatch: (String text) {
    spans.add(TextSpan(text: text));
    return '';
  });
  // print('input: "$input", spans: $spans');
  return TextSpan(style: style, children: spans);
}
```

you can test it with:

```
  final span = rich('''
⦁ nested multistyle:

    some _italic words that can be *bold* too_
    or _~italic & lineThrough~_
    or even _*~3 in 1~*_

⦁ _italic_ style
⦁ *bold* style
⦁ ~lineThrough~ style''',
    // style: is optional here
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.blue[900])
  );
  // and now you can use span in
  //   Text.rich(span)
```

**EDIT2**

for monospace code (```some code here```) you can use:

````
TextSpan rich(String input, {TextStyle? style}) {
  const styles = {
    '_': TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
    '*': TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    '~': TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough),
    '```': TextStyle(fontFamily: 'monospace', color: Colors.black87),
  };
  final spans = <TextSpan>[];
  final pattern = RegExp(r'([_*~]|`{3})(.*?)\1');
  input.trim().splitMapJoin(pattern, onMatch: (m) {
    final input = m.group(2)!;
    final style = styles[m.group(1)];
    spans.add(
      pattern.hasMatch(input)?
      rich(input, style: style) : TextSpan(text: input, style: style)
    );
    return '';
  }, onNonMatch: (String text) {
    spans.add(TextSpan(text: text));
    return '';
  });
  // print('input: "$input", spans: $spans');
  return TextSpan(style: style, children: spans);
}
````

the sample usage:

````
    final span = rich('''
⦁ nested multistyle:

    some _italic words that can be *bold* too_
    or _~italic & lineThrough~_
    or ```monospaced code with *bold* word```
    or even _*~3 in 1~*_

⦁ _italic_ style
⦁ *bold* style
⦁ ~lineThrough~ style
⦁ ```code``` style''',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.blue[900])
    );
    return Text.rich(span);
````

Comment: Thanks alot, What if I want to capture multiple combinations, for example ~*some text*~

Comment: Nice, It is working well, thanks alot. Btw, I want to include Monospace - font family with three ```some text```. How can I go about that?

Comment: Sorry, I mean ``` This symbol `, How is it called?

Comment: Great, Thanks alot

Comment: If I have the text has HTML tags, How can I get style the string between two HTML tags? For example: <h1>Hello, World<h1> OR <h2>Hello, World <p>Welcome</p></h2

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex that will have a match if you either have `_ some text _`, `*some text*` or `~some text~`, hopefully that solves your issue:

```
([_~*])(.*?)\1
```

of course, it also matches `__`, `~~` and `**`

Here is the [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/a-0g8eUk41VTwwRQ)

Example of usage:

```
void main() {
  String txt = '_some text_ some *more* text, and some ~final~ text';
  RegExp regex = RegExp('([_~*])(.*?)\\1');
  
  if (regex.hasMatch(txt)) {
    for (var match in regex.allMatches(txt)) 
    {
      String text = match.group(2)!;
      String delimiter = match.group(1)!;
      switch (delimiter) {
        case '_':
          print('underscore');
          break;
        case '~':
          print('tilde');
          break;
        case '*':
          print('star');
          break;
      }
      print(text);
    }
  }
}
```

the above will print

```
underscore
some text
star
more
tilde
final
```

### Edit 2:

[User pskink's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70245076/12638504) has a better example of usage for this regex

Comment: This is a nice answer, but I am wondering how I will write a conditional statement... I want if the string is `*some text*` then return a bold string, else if `_ some text _` then return an italic string else `~some text~` then return a strikethrough decoration. I hope you get what I mean

Comment: yes, I edited my answer to change the regex a bit and added an example of usage