# How to detect text inside specific character on Dart

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I am trying to create a function to detect if some text is encapsuled by a special symbol/character , so if i have  String  :

```
String text = 'This is normal String, <b> This is Bold String <b>';
```

i would get a List of Map like this :

```
 [ {'This is Normal String' : 'normal'} , 
    {'This is Bold String' : 'bold'} ]
```

Then i can rewrite it on RichText,

What i have tried is splitting the text like this: `List<String> list = text.split('<b>');`
and make the even index of the list bold, but it will not behave the way i wanted if the bold tag is on the front of the text , and if i need to detect another character like `<i>` , is there any way to do this ?
Thankyou

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70219234/how-to-write-a-reg-expression-of-a-string-that-contains-two-tilde-or-two-und/70245076#70245076

Answer (score -1):

```
var string = 'I am here';
string.contains('h');// true
//You can use Regex to find patterns inside a string
string.contains(new RegExp(r'[A-Z]'));  // true
```

Comment: That is very broad. Any actual ideas how to use those functions to do what the OP is asking?