# Split a string by a regex pattern and include the regex match in the results?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have sample text as follows:

```
Test1 [url="http://www.stackoverflow.com"]Stack Overflow[/url], Test2 Lorem Ipsum Etc...
```

What I am trying to do is split this string into a `List` using the `url` pattern as the delineator.

What I've been able to do so far is this:

```
var parsedList = mystring.split(RegExp(r'\[url=["]?([\s\S]*?)["]?\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/url\]', caseSensitive: false));
```

That is breaking up the string into a `List` but is not including the actual matched `url` pattern in the results, the result I get is:

**Actual Result**

```
[
Test 1
, Test2 Lorem Ipsum Etc...
]
```

**Expected Result**

```
[
Test 1
[url="http://www.stackoverflow.com"]Stack Overflow[/url]
, Test2 Lorem Ipsum Etc...
]
```

Is there anyway for my string split to include the matched pattern in the result list?

Comment: you could use `String.splitMapJoin` method - here is how i made some parts of string bold / italic / line-trough: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70245076/2252830

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the search text with `splitMapJoin()` and split it.

Example:

```dart
void main() {
  final text = 'Test1 [url="http://www.stackoverflow.com"]Stack Overflow[/url], Test2 Lorem Ipsum Etc...';

  var split = text
      .splitMapJoin(
        RegExp(r'\[url=.*\]'),
        onMatch: (m) => '#${m[0]}#',
        onNonMatch: (m) => m,
      )
      .split('#');

  split.forEach(print);
}
```

Output:

```
Test1 
[url="http://www.stackoverflow.com"]Stack Overflow[/url]
, Test2 Lorem Ipsum Etc...
```