# How to make bold a specific portion of a dynamic string in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, package, richtext, bold

I am getting a message from the server like - THE ONLY MARATHON YOU'VE EVER DONE IS A MOVIE MARATHON. GET OFF THE COUCH *CHUNKY BUTT* AND DO SOME CARDIO. I have to make it bolder those character which is in asterisks. I am using flutter package "simple_text". It's working but not as like expectation. So, could anyone please help me with sharing effective suggestions? Here you go with my code and output screenshot. Thanks in advance!

```
SimpleRichText(

                "THE ONLY MARATHON YOU'VE EVER DONE IS A MOVIE MARATHON. GET OFF THE COUCH *CHUNKY BUTT* AND DO SOME CARDIO.",

                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 35.0,
                    fontFamily: 'SFPRO',
                    color: white,
                    letterSpacing: 1,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                  ),
                ),
```

[image]

Comment: you like to make blood textStyle on `CHUNKY BUTT`, also is it fixed that there will be single pair on string data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70219234/how-to-write-a-reg-expression-of-a-string-that-contains-two-tilde-or-two-und#70245076

Comment: How do you receive it formatted ? html ? markdown ? bbcode ?

Answer (score 1):

RichText widget

[image]

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Hello ',
    style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
    children: const <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer btw. But I am getting random string from the server periodically like-   GET OFF THE ***COUCH CHUNKY*** BUTT AND DO SOME CARDIO. I have to make bold which is in asterisk and asterisk can be anywhere in other sentence or string. So, do you have any solution for that? Thanks!

Comment: @KafiulIslam have you tried the link I posted? if so, what's unclear?

Comment: @pskink Maybe my question is not clear to you. If you like we can make a quick call. 
live:.cid.e445ec689922a0b5
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you receive some Markdown formatting from server (?)

So you can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown to parse it and render it

```
Markdown(
    controller: controller,
    selectable: true,
    data: 'Hey *there*',
)
```